# How to programmatically switch screens?

Tags: xcode, swift2, xcode7

How do you programmatically change screens? I've got the play button in my projects main.storyboard and have everything positioned, I'm going to connect the play button from the storyboard to the GameScene.swift. Is there any way you can help me?

Comment: is it possible with storyboard id .

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. XCode only changed the language a tiny bit, so there'd be no problem

Comment: ok i will try and let you know

Comment: Thanks a lot, Uma :)

Comment: What is the code you entered?

Comment: You can pass  segue identifier.. It is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include this code button function.

```
    var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as! ViewController
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the following code according to your storyboard and view controller name. Then you can use it.

```
let yourStoryboardName = UIStoryboard(name: "YourStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let yourViewControllerName = yourStoryboardName.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YourViewControllerName") as! YourViewControllerName
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(yourViewControllerName, animated: true)
```